# Amazon IAM Policy for BrowseNodeLookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I was wondering if someone could tell me what Policy I need to attach to authorize myself for the BrowseNodeLookUp on the Amazon Product Advertisement API. Somehow I can't seem to find any Information on this and for all my request I receive

```
[Code] => UnauthorizedOperation
[Message] => Your AccessKeyId is not authorized to perform this operation. Please check IAM policies for the Access Key.
```

So I would very much appreciate a little pointer here
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Product Advertising API does not support IAM roles. You must use
>   the root account credentials. ([Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/becomingDev.html))

If you are using an IAM user you must use the root account credentials instead. (So there is no IAM policy for `BrowseNodeLookUp` - relevant [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=289929) on AWS support forums.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where can I find the root account credentials?

Comment: Log into the AWS console. In the top-right click your name and click Security Credentials. You'll see an Access and Secret Key section. They are under there. Better description at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html